# MongoDB query with condition or without

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a simple problem in my node.js/mongodb application. When requesting `/api/house` I want ALL the houses, unconditionally, and when requesting `/api/house?rooms=2&area=100` I want only houses with two rooms AND with an area of 100.

My database contains a lot of houses with fields `area` and `rooms` being `null` or `undefined`, so I want to match these when requesting ALL houses. Otherwise, use the specified paramater value. I don't know how to do that.

My relevant code is:

```
app.get('/api/house', function (req, res) {
    House.find({})
    .and([
        { area: new RegExp(req.query.area ? req.query.area : '', 'i') },
        { numberOfRooms: req.query.numberofrooms ? req.query.rooms : { $gte: 0 } }
    ])
    .exec(function (err, estates) {
        if (estates)
            return res.send(estates);
        res.status(500).send({ error: err.message });
    });
});
```

This will work for houses having non-null/undefined fields because they are strings or numbers, but will skip those that doesn't.

My `House` schema:

```
area: { type: String },
rooms: { type: Number }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to write one statement that satisfies both scenarios?  Just write two.

Comment: @BanksySan Just because it seems doable I guess. How would I write a query to match every house, included those with `null` and `undefined` in their fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a query like this:

```
db.houses.find({
    $and: [
        $or: [
            { rooms: 2 },
            { rooms: { $exists: false } },
        ],
        $or: [
            { area: "100" },
            { area: { $exists: false } },
        ],
    ],
});
```

which should cover *all* of your cases.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an OR in addition to your AND logic to match null and undefined values. A single query in javascript would look like this

P.S: You might need to add a few more conditions to the ones listed below to satisfy your needs.

```
db.houses.find(
    {$or: [
        {rooms:2, area:"100"},
        {rooms:"null", area:"null"},
        {rooms:"undefined", area:"undefined"}
]});
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
House.find({}, function(err, houseArray){ // the find function returns an array
  if(err) throw err;
  if(houseArray.length > 0){
    //your code goes here
  } else if(houseArray.length == 0){
    //notify the user or throw err etc.
  }
})
```

and if you want a specific parameter you'd have to write something like:

```
House.find({'rooms': 3})
```

or if you want greater than and less that a specific number you'd have to do something like:

```
House.find({'rooms': {$gt: 0, $lt: 5}})
```

and then continue with your code! Hope I helped!